# How time.After and time.Tick works in default-selection.go in tour of go?

Tags: go

```
package main
import(
"fmt"
"time"
)
func main(){
tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
for {
select{
case <-tick:
fmt.Println("tick")
case <-boom:
fmt.Println("BOOM!")
return
default:
fmt.Println("  .")
time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
}
}
}
```

Can somebody explain step by step execution of the code ?
https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6

Comment: Have you seen the docs for [time.After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) and [time.Tick](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick)? If not, please do so, then explain if you still have questions.

Comment: Would be good if you explain what is the specific aspect of the code that you don't understand. Also, reading the documentation @Flimzy suggested could help.

Answer (score -2):

**select** can only handle 1 case at a time, and it will handle cases one by one (*Thanks @Flimzy for correcting*).

**tick.Tick()** will send a signal every 100 mills, while **time.After()** will send a signal after 500 mills.

Which means **select** will response to default case when there's no signal coming out from **tick()** or **after()**.

Comment: "it will handle cases in order" -- This is not true. The order in which it handles multiple ready cases is non-deterministic.

Comment: Apologize for my mistake, I mean the cases are handled one by one actually.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to update your answer to say that, then.